# Upgrading existing windows applicatioon to .net 3.5 framework

Tags: .net, .net-3.5

We have a .net 2.0 windows application already deployed to client machines.
Now, we have want to upgrade it to .Net 3.5 framework.But client machines may not have this new framework installed.

Can someone please let me know how to achieve this using VS.Net setup and deployment project?

Also, after deployment to client machine, when the user clicks on new msi package, then it should automatically update the existing package or install new one if not existing already.Help on this would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: What do you want to do if the client machine is not running .NET 3.5?

Comment: I would want the MSI package to install it incase it does not have 3.5 framework already.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to properties->prerequisites and check .Net 3.5

Comment: thanks Alex for your response.Yes,I could figure that out myself.Wanted to know which radio button option is recommended for .Net 3.5 installation from the three  options mentioned over there?

Comment: So why did not you tell it in your question? Do you think I can read you mind?

Comment: I happened to find the solution after posting the question over here.I just wanna know which radio button option to select from the 3 options.Thanks for your response.

Comment: I have Client Profile, 3.0, 3.5 and 3.5SP1 in the list. You should choose the one you need. What are 3 options that you mentioned?

Comment: Here r those 3 options:1.Download prerequisites from the component's vendor site
2.Download prerequisites from thr same location as my application
3.Download prerequisites from the following location.Thanks.

Comment: Select option 1 so the setup will download it from microsoft.com